# User-defined MySQL variables in Laravel 3?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to update the "rank" for a group of MySQL records with sequential numbers using a user-defined variable. The following query runs fine via the MySQL command line:

```
SET @rank:=0; UPDATE scores SET rank=@rank:=@rank+1 WHERE game_id=4 ORDER BY score DESC
```

But if I try and run it as a Fluent query using Laravel, it fails.

```
DB::query("SET @rank:=0; UPDATE scores SET rank=@rank:=@rank+1 WHERE game_id=4 ORDER BY score DESC");
```

Error message:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL 
syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near 'UPDATE scores SET rank=@rank:=@rank+1 WHERE game_id=4 ORDER BY' at line 1

SQL: SET @rank:=0; UPDATE scores SET rank=@rank:=@rank+1 WHERE game_id=4 ORDER BY score DESC

Bindings: array (
)
```

**[SOLVED]**

DB::raw() to the rescue! The following works:

```
DB::query(DB::raw("SET @rank:=0"));
DB::query("UPDATE scores SET rank=@rank:=@rank+1 WHERE game_id=4 ORDER BY score DESC");
```

Comment: +1. Very interesting. I'd be interested in finding the answer to this too.

Comment: The point is that's not one statement, but two.  Set the user variable from one query, then *using the same database connection*, run your update.

Comment: I tried that. Trying to run just the "SET @rank:=0" query results in the following error: "Method [] is not defined on the Query class."

Comment: @JamieTibbetts can you provide a stack trace for that error?

Comment: The stack trace for DB::query("SET @rank:=0") is too long to fit in a comment, but here's a screen shot of it: [link](http://f.cl.ly/items/2l2T1Z1R2p3L3F0j2v0f/Screen%20Shot%202013-05-01%20at%2011.48.39%20AM.png)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to execute multiple statements in one query.  Laravel uses PDO under the hood which prevents this.  You could attempt to call this over 2 queries instead, since `@rank` should be available for the duration of the connection.

```
DB::query("SET @rank:=0");
DB::query("UPDATE scores SET rank=@rank:=@rank+1 WHERE game_id=? ORDER BY score DESC", array(4));
```

Comment: Actually, PDO has supported batched statements since it switched to the PHP-native MySQL driver in v5.3.

Comment: I tried that. It doesn't work either. The first query throws an error: "Method [] is not defined on the Query class."

Comment: This solution was really close. The first query just need to use DB::raw(). e.g. DB::query(DB::raw("SET @rank:=0"));

Comment: Is there any concern for a race condition when executing in multiple statements? For example another process executes at the same time and changes @rank

Comment: @VladVinnikov I don't know if I'm honest.  I believe that variables like this are per-connection – so if the connection is being pooled correctly then it should have no such problems.  If you're trying to run this in more recent Laravel you could use a transaction to tighten this up.