# Laravel: User-defined MySQL variables always NULL in Laravel but not in MySQL CLI

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I have a query with a nested select that uses the result of the first select. I have the query working perfectly as I tested using Sequel Pro's query checker. It returns my desired results. When I pass this query over to Laravel and run a test on it using a simple `echo` statement, it outputs `NULL`.

Here is my PHP code and query:

```
$crons = DB::select('
    SELECT @quiet_crons:=ROUND(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(`end_time`, `start_time`))/60/15))
    AS quiet_crons,
    FLOOR(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME('24:00'), TIME(NOW())))/60/15-@quiet_crons))
    AS remaining_crons
    FROM `quiet_periods`
    WHERE `day` = DAYNAME(NOW())
');
```

And this is the output from the console:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#689 (2) {
    ["quiet_crons"]=>
    string(2) "24"
    ["remaining_crons"]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

The `remaining_crons` result should never be `NULL`.

*Please Note:* I saw an article on here that talked about user-defined MySQL variables in Laravel and I tried the solution yet it did not solve my problem. This is the link I am referring to:
[User-defined MySQL variables in Laravel 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319132/user-defined-mysql-variables-in-laravel-3)

Answer (score 2):

MySQL user defined variables are a bit tricky. From [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html);

> As a general rule, other than in SET statements, ***you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement***. For example, to increment a variable, this is okay:
>
> SET @a = @a + 1;
>
> For other statements, such as SELECT, ***you might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed***. In the following statement, you might think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then do an assignment second:
>   ...

You can rewrite the statement without the variable though;

```sql
SELECT quiet_crons, 
  FLOOR(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME('24:00'), TIME(NOW())))/60/15-quiet_crons))
  AS remaining_crons
FROM (
  SELECT ROUND(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(`end_time`, `start_time`))/60/15))
  AS quiet_crons
  FROM `quiet_periods`
  WHERE `day` = DAYNAME(NOW())
) a;
```

[An SQfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc8f2/1).

Comment: I think I was beginning to understand that the above was the case. I don't understand how MySQL would just do it anyway and produce the results without `SET`?

Comment: @JoshuaStewart The order of evaluation may depend on a lot, but as far as I understand it, the optimizer is free to evaluate things in any order disregarding the variable assignments, so that may very well change with a few more rows inserted in the table/another query plan. Risky to rely on either way when it's documented to be non reliable.

Comment: I'll take that into consideration, I might note that I trialled your solution yet it was producing results 20 less than what I was expecting, should you know why this is?

Comment: @JoshuaStewart Do you have any sample data and a required result that isn't correct that can be used for testing? If there's a lot of data, rounding can increase or decrease the total quite a bit from the average when tested over a period of 15 minutes.

Comment: Yes, I understand that and I proposed this thought to the person in charge of development but they disregarded this and suggested it was not a concern.

Comment: @JoshuaStewart For `quiet_crons`, it's not a concern, for `remaining_crons` it may cause it to vary since it's a value calculated from `NOW()`.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, it is a bit weird but as soon as I `SET` (initialise) the variable first in a separate query, the resulting query works fine in Laravel.

Here is my code that I added above the previous code:

```
$crons = DB::select(DB::raw('
    SET @quiet_crons = 0;
'));
```

Maybe someone could explain why this works the way it does in Laravel when MySQL just does it's thing and works anyway...